# is it possible to automate website input

Tags: c#, html-parsing

I've got a question of one of my colleagues about writing a programm for downloading images of a webshop.

I've got an excel list with article numbers. For finding the right product this number has to be inserted to the findbox of the webshop. How could it be possible to write a program that finds this product en returns the page source for parsing.

Kind regards,
Luuk Krijnen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the url of the search site...
For example at Stackoverflow it looks like that:

```
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=testsearch
```

Or look at ebay:

```
http://www.ebay.de/itm/330813122179
```

so you can just add the searchtext/article-numbers.

[getting source of webpage](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/194151/getting-source-of-webpage)

```
string getPageSource(string URL)
{
    System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
    string strSource = webClient.DownloadString(URL);
    webClient.Dispose();
    return strSource;
}
```

Hint:save the excel list as a CSV

Answer (score 2):

Review the [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) class.

You will also find [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) useful to track what the browsers sends to the server (so you can reproduce that in your code).